# Minify min.js files in word press

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, performance, plugins, google-pagespeed

I am working on a project in which i have created reactjs plugin for wordpress and we are using kadence theme. I check the performance(google speed test) of my page and on mobile it is 80%. I want to increase the performace of website but i am stuck.
I cant further reduce the size. There are some unused JS that i want to remove.As they are min.js so i have no idea how to further reduce the min.js files.

[This is the original tree structure of JS files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp6cy.png)

[UnUsed JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDNPi.png)

Is there any way that i can further reduce the size of JS files and increase the performance.

thanks

I google the internet but cant find the solution.